# How to allow editing some field in some collections MondoDB Realm?

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

I need to allow write for all users in some field one of my collection

All my data save in MondoDB Atlas and I sync it in the "Sync" MongoDB Realm.

I have some troubles with my task

If in the rules "Sync" I set:
read - true
write - false
and in the collection set these rules:

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "apply_when": {
        "%%true": true
      },
      "insert": false,
      "delete": false,
      "search": true,
      "read": true,
      "write": false,
      "fields": {
        "countViews": {
          "write": true
        },
        "listViewers": {
          "write": true
        }
      },
      "additional_fields": {}
    }
  ],
  "filters": [],
```

Then have this error:
Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Received: ERROR "Permission denied (BIND, REFRESH) - request logs URL: link” (error_code=206, try_again=true)

But if I set rules for sync:
read - allow
write - allow
All users can write data in any fields and collection, despite the rules in the collection

So, I can't understand where I make mistake and what rules should I set in the Sync. Rules for Sync > rules for Collection? Or it's mistake in the rules for collection, that I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that document level write permissions take priority over field level ones.

The rules in your question have write: false

```
"roles": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "apply_when": {
        "%%true": true
      },
      "write": false,   <- document level write is FALSE which takes priority
```

but then the field level rules are true but are overridden

```
"fields": {
   "countViews": {
      "write": true
   },
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/query-roles/#advanced-role-patterns)

> Document-level write permissions take priority over any field-level
> permissions. If a role has a document-level write rule, it applies to
> all fields in the document and cannot be overridden.

There are a number of solutions; omit the document level rule and specify the rules on the individual fields. Or add the 'additional_fields' rule to blanket apply a rule to fields you don't supply rules for.

```
"additional_fields": { "write": true }
```

Comment: I tried it without this line also. It isn't change anything and not solve my problem 
I think that problem can be it 2 places:
1.) "Sync", because when I set write to true, user can write data in any field (I need only in 2 field one of collections). But if write will be false, user can't write anywhere. Maybe I need customise something here?
2.) My rules have some error and it isn't working

Comment: @AleksandrProkopenko I understand. If you attempted something other ways, you should include that in the question so we have more info about what troubleshooting you've done - and it helps us write better answers because we have accurate data to work with. As you can see my answer is correct based on the info in the question. If you can clarify the question we'll take another look and see what we can suggest.